# Getting Javascript Variable into php without using post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi i have made a php function  that has to be called from script tag since the value is generated from javascript. In short i have to execute php function dynamically in one page itself. The think i can achieve is that i can call a function with static parameters such as

```
$(".countryoptions").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log(<?php echo json_encode(getRegions(NULL,NULL));?>);
    console.log(<?php echo json_encode(getRegions(NULL,"$(this).val()"));?>);
});
```

The first two values are been printed as expected but the third makes me sad, values are been passed as string ("$(this).val()") itself not the value. It may be stupid but is there any way to encounter this problem without POST request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you were asking but change the double quotes to single quotes. The dollar symbol gets executed as a variable in double quotes unless you escape it or use single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Use a GET request, but seriously the php code is executed on the server before the browser even gets the js to execute.

Comment: Musa... my point for the question is i can call a php function but why cant i can call with javascript generated value.

Comment: ok got it... The value which is printed is been computed previously and the value generated will replace the php tags .. Sorry for vague question and thanks Dvorak for getting me clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a client-side language, and PHP is server-side. PHP has no control over the page elements once the page has been loaded. What you're trying to do now is echo the values in your console using `<?php` tags. This will not work.

If you want to access the PHP variables in your JS code, you can use a [`GET`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/%E2%80%8E) request or even [`POST`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. php tags without quotes works fine executing php function and gets me values.The post request prompts me for page refresh that a problem and i have to do it dynamically.

Comment: @PRASANTH see also the duplicate question I've linked

Comment: @PRASANTH: Nope, a pageload isn't required. See the docs :)

Comment: Thanks Amal Murali... I will look for some ajax request ..That will get a way out.